# Visual Studio 2022 Worker Service

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2022

I just installed the new version of Visual Studio (2022) and I miss the template for worker services. Does this no longer exist?

Thanks a lot and best Regards,

Hendriks91

Comment: as workaround use "dotnet new worker"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem (worker service and blazor templates were missing) and this is what I did to get them back:

- I double-checked what features and tools I had installed in VS 2019 where all my project templates were still present and noticed I was missing 'ASP.NET and web development'. I ticked this box in the Visual Studio installer and installed the relevant tools. At first this made no difference.
- I then checked where VS normally stores its project templates. I found this article useful: [Where default templates are stored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20templates%20installed%20with,Language%3E%5C)
  Note Visual Studio 2022 gets installed under Program Files (64 bit, not 86x)
  To my surprise, all missing templates were there.
- I then decided to repair VS 2022 via the VS installer. It then prompted me to restart my PC (which it hadn't done before).
- Finally, after the restart I could see the project templates again.

I guess the reason for my VS 2022 not having those templates at first was because I deselected F# components under 'Individual Components' in the installer, which then removed a few other tools and features as well.

I also saw an article online suggesting to install the .Net SDK (but it was already installed for me). [Download .Net SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.101-windows-x64-installer)

I speculate repairing VS did the trick because my internet connection was also not very stable at the time that I installed it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution to the problem, but a quick **workaround**:

While repairing Visual Studio takes time and you probably don't want to do it during work hours, you can use dotnet CLI to create a new worker service very quickly and easily. Just execute:

```
dotnet new worker -o [MY-PROJECT-NAME]
```

Some tips:

- You can list all the installed project templates by running
  "dotnet new list"
- Usually the worker service is a project to manage the execution or life cycle of another project. In that case, just run the dotnet command inside the solution folder of the main project, then in VS right click the solution => Add => Existing Project and pick the worker service project.

Thanks!